# How to find cost data for commercially available spacecraft components?

Tags: propulsion, spacecraft, cost

I'm trying to research how much it should cost to build a small spacecraft, but it's super hard to find good information on the cost of various components. Can anyone suggest any good resources? For example, aerojet rocketdyne say that the [NEXT-C thruster](https://www.rocket.com/sites/default/files/documents/NEXT-C_Data_sheet_01_2022_FINAL_DIGITAL.pdf) will be or is commercially available - but is there any way to figure out the cost without talking to each company, signing an NDA etc? Or if not for this specific thruster, for some class of thruster technology and thrust?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this isn't a bad question at all, everybody at some point goes through the same thoughts. It can arise, for example, in university design studies where the organisation doesn't have direct purchasing history for a range of items.

I know this site doesn't like link only answers but the nature of the question is more or less that it is asking for an example link.

This is an example source of price information, it is specific to that company, their commercial and delivery terms etc etc so it won't be a good guide to anyone else's prices. Its pretty rare that companies announce prices publically. Anyway, an example component price list:

http://www.pumpkininc.com/content/doc/forms/pricelist.pdf

In this case the pricelist itself probably isn't sufficient to work out what half the items even are, that will involve a fair bit of digging around the rest of their site. The Pumpkin pricelist is linked to from this other site:

http://www.cubesatkit.com/#